# Selecting child elements in groups, and treating each group differently

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have multiple list items in a `<ul>`, and there are groups of items than contain the `.aggregated` class. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
    <li class="aggregated"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to style each of those groups of `<li>` elements differently, basically giving each group a different background color. So, the first group of `<li class="aggregated">` would have a blue background, and the second group a yellow background, etc. I don't want to rely on JS and don't want to add arbitrary class names or IDs. I'd like to use the code that's already in place.

Possible? If so, how?

Comment: I'm assuming your wanting something more than `ul li.aggregated { background-color:red; }` ?

Comment: Yes. Each group should be a different color.

Comment: No, it's not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to do it with just CSS, as you've asked in your edit.

Comment: @BrandonDurham, have you taken a look at my solution below? I think it is along the lines of what you are looking for but it is hard to tweak it to your needs without additional input

That said, I think the only way you are going to achieve this with the HTML you put in place is with JS unfortunately.

Comment: @BoltClock: Maybe it is possible after all: http://jsfiddle.net/8JxFP/. My brain is melting.

Comment: @thirtydot: So basically, something like `E:first-child + E + E` but with `:not()` and `~`? Yes, my brain is melting too.

Comment: @BoltClock, well... [*actually*...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10824647/82548) =) Oh, gorramit. I hadn't realised that thirtydot had already implemented that. Sigh...and I thought I was so clever... =/

Comment: @David Thomas, thirtydot: Is this the part where we say it "happens to the best of us"?

Comment: @DavidThomas: I didn't really want to write up an answer anyway (I don't think a pure CSS solution is particularly sensible in this situation). Also, your selectors are shorter.

Comment: @thirtydot, I agree with the point about 'sensible,' but as a...thought exercise it was fun. Though it took a little longer than it should to put it together; albeit once put-together it *feels* like a hack from the old days (pre-2009, for goodness' sake..!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this *is* possible. But it's insanely fragile, and relies on there being predictable classes, also it requires a modern browser:

```
/* presentational stuff */

li ~ li.aggregated,
li.aggregated ~ li.aggregated {
    background-color: #f90;
}

li.aggregated ~ li:not(.aggregated) ~ li.aggregated {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

li.aggregated ~ li:not(.aggregated) ~ li.aggregated ~ li:not(.aggregated) ~ li.aggregated {
    background-color: #cfc;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HH99P/).

Comment: Oh, and there is nothing currently in CSS4 that could make these selectors shorter. So, carry on...

Comment: There isn't? Honestly, I'd've thought 'grouping' would be...I dunno, a sensible thing to try and implement?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at any item that has the class where the element before it does not, you can define group numbers and increment them accordingly.

```
var groupNum = 1;
// Get all <li>
$("ul li").each( function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if( element.hasClass("aggregated") ) {
        if( !element.prev().hasClass("aggregated") ) {
            // Prev element was not in this group. increment the group number
            groupNum++;
        }
        switch( groupNum ) {
            case 1:
                // group #1 styles
                // element.css( "background-color", "#FFF" );
                break;
            case 2:
                // group #2 styles
                // element.css( "background-color", "#00F" );
                break;
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: great answer although you need to replace `this` with `$(this)`. See a fiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/99wqG/

Answer (score 1):

You could use different classes for the different bgColors, or add a 2nd class to the groups and put the bgColor in those classes (if you have some purpose they must all have aggregated class).

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg1"></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg1"></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg1"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg2"></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg2"></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg2"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg3"></li>
    <li class="aggregated bg3"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding custom class to each list item of the group you can group the items with a div, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div class="group">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Then you can select the groups you are interested in using `nth-of-type` selector, for example:

```
ul > .group:nth-of-type(1) > li
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

`nth-of-type` selector allows you to select items by number, keyword, or formula.

---

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTxGv/1/).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's invalid HTML. Although it will work in browsers, it's obviously not good.